# node.js recursive download of chunked array with promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, ecmascript-6, promise

I want to download a lot of images (1000+), so I split the Array into chunks of specified size and download them one after another. The downloads are promise based and resolve once a chunk is finished. Without using chunks everything works fine, but with this implementation the following happens:

```
console.log("Promise Recursive resolved", paths);
```

get called in the downloadRecursive function once it finishes, but it does not resolve as expected, so

```
console.log("Finished");
```

does not get called in the downloadAll function.

```
function downloadAll(folder, full_size, images) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        // Chunks of all images [ [1,2,3,4,5], [6,7,8,9,10], [...] ]
        let grouped_images = chunk(images, 5);

        downloadRecursive(folder, full_size, grouped_images, 1, []).then(function (e) {
            console.log("Finished");
            resolve(e);
        }).catch(function () {
            reject();
        });
    });
}


function downloadRecursive(folder, full_size, all, part, paths) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        if(part > all.length){
            console.log("Promise Recursive resolved", paths);
            resolve(paths);
        }

        downloadImages(folder, all[part-1], full_size).then(function (e) {
            paths.push(e);
            return downloadRecursive(folder, full_size, all, part+1, paths);
        });
    });
}


function downloadImages(folder, images, full_size=true) {
    [...]

    return Promise.all(images.map(function (image) {
        [...]
        return doDownload(...);
    }));
}

function doDownload(url, path, full_size){
    returns promise
}
```

Comment: You may find Bluebird's `Promise.map()` with its concurrency option to be very useful.  It solves problems like this.  How to run a large number of async operations with no more than N in flight at the same time.

Comment: Creating new promises like that is an anti-pattern. Instead of doing "`new Promise(...)...`" and then calling resolve / reject from `.then` and `.catch` ditch the `new Promise` and just return your promise chain. See: http://jf.io/2016/10/09/promises#anti-patterns-explicit-construction-promises-everywhere

Comment: I agree with the above, and the problem might be that you don't return after calling `resolve` in `downloadRecursive`, so it will run `downloadImages` an extra time, and that may fail.

Comment: in downloadRecursive, the preomise is never resolved or rejected unless `(part > all.length)` - so, you'll have "pending" promises

Comment: `Promise.map()` looks good. I will look into that, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a recursive call, try using `array#reduce` like so

```
function downloadAll(folder, full_size, images) {
    return chunk(images, 5)
    .reduce((promsie, chunk) => 
        promise.then((array) => 
            downloadImages(folder, chunk, full_size)
            .then(result => 
                array.concat(result)
            )
        ), Promise.resolve([])
    );
}


function downloadImages(folder, images, full_size=true) {
    [...]
    return Promise.all(images.map(function (image) {
        [...]
        return doDownload(...);
    }));
}

function doDownload(url, path, full_size){
    returns promise
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to catch and find out the error that is breaking the chain so you can debug what is happening along the way:

```
    downloadRecursive(folder, full_size, grouped_images, 1, []).then(function (result) {
        console.log("Finished");
        resolve(result);
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log("error in recursion:", error);
        reject(error);
    });
```

Worst case if you can't avoid a couple errors in 1000+ images, then you may want to add a catch() block to the problematic code and just suppress the error and allow the loop to continue.

Comment: the chain isn't broken by an error ... the fact is that Promise returned in `downloadRecursive` is only ever resolved once `part > all.length` ... and the recursion does not do any chaining anyway! he could (I think) `resolve(downloadRecursive(...))` instead of `return downloadRecursive` - but that's still very ugly code if it even works ...

Comment: Multiple definitions to the word chain

Comment: seriously? semantics? I'm talking about (the non-existence of) the promise chain - how is the final "resolution" going to make it's way up the recursion to resolve the Promise created in the first call?

Comment: Thanks for the solution: `resolve(downloadRecursive(...))` seems to work, I will further test this later. You say this is ugly code, how would you implement the whole process in a better way, with the reduce example above?